# Invoking action from ajax method is throwing an error: The required anti-forgery form field "__RequestVerificationToken" is not present

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, ajax, asp.net-mvc-5

I have the following ajax method which triggers action method from the controller. On executing the below method I see an error: The required anti-forgery form field "__RequestVerificationToken" is not present. But in the view source I see there is a form field "__RequestVerificationToken" which I am passing it the action method.

**Test.cshtml:**

```
<form action="javascript: void(0)" id="frmContent">
 @Html.AntiForgeryToken()
</form>

<script type="text/javascript" charset="utf8">
  var vue_data = vue_data || {};

    (function () {
            var token = $('#frmContent input[name=__RequestVerificationToken]').val();
            $.ajax({
                    url: '@(Url.Action("GetData", "Test"))',
                    type: "POST",
                    cache: false,
                    async: false,
                    headers: {
                        "__RequestVerificationToken": token
                    },
                    data: { search: $('#search').val()},
                    success: function (data) {
                        var items = jQuery.parseJSON(data);
                        vue_data.view_content = items.items;
                    }
                });
            })();

</script>
```

**TestController.cs**

```
[ValidateHeaderAntiForgeryToken]
public JsonResult GetData(string search)
{
}
```

Can anyone help me to fix this issue?

Comment: The entire point of using an anti-forgery token is to make sure the form data is not being tampered with by man in the middle attacks, if you could do what you are trying to do here, then the anti-forgery token is pointless. because you are trying to manipulate it. Its intended to be sent in a form submit. that's why you have the html helper, because there is encryption going on, so when you try and send the token it fails because its been altered

Answer (score 0):

you can also pass antiforgerytoken in data. I have used it before and it works like a charm.

```
 data: { "__RequestVerificationToken": token,"search": $('#search').val()}
```

On your actionMethod use:
    [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
Also, this will not work.
    data: {search: $('#search').val()}
please use quotes with search:
    data: { "__RequestVerificationToken": token,"search": $('#search').val()}

Comment: Thanks Abhishek for your response.  I tried the same as per your response but it still is throwing the same error.The required anti-forgery form field \"__RequestVerificationToken\" is not present.

Comment: Please check if you are getting the value in token. Also in your code your are passing data as
    data: { search: $('#search').val()},
it should be 
    data: { "__RequestVerificationToken": token,"search": $('#search').val()}